# Include jQuery datatables in webpack.ProvidePlugin on webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, datatables

I am currently importing jQuery datatables on every javascript file I create.

```
import 'datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables';
import 'datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4';

$('#example').DataTable();
```

Is it possible to make it global that I'm not required to import it everytime? jQuery has this behavior and I'm able to access `$` on every javascript without importing it.

In my **environment.js**, I currently have this:

```
const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

I believe that this is the file that loads packages globally. Is it possible to include datatables here?

So far I have tried this:

```
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
  DataTable: 'datatables.net'
}));
```

And this:

```
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
  DataTable: 'datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables'
}));
```

But no luck. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: All you need is to define jQuery as external.  Don't worry about DataTable.  You're going to include jQuery on the page anyway, then just include DataTable after it.   Pick what you need from the download page: https://datatables.net/download/ and include after jQuery on the page from external/cdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, foud some helpfull things on this link https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32542/datatables-and-webpack , maby you should use dt instead of DataTable

Comment: Giving a link is useful but it doesn't provide the answer. It's better to share some code sample code